# Validate JWT token in .Net

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application to save Azure Active Directory users to SQL Server. For this I am using MSAL authentication to get the users.

But sometimes my access token will get expired and I will get 401 unauthorized error from Graph. So I need to add the logic of validating the expiry in my code itself. I searched a lot but couldn't find a good solution.

Could anybody help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The default lifetime of an access token is variable. When issued, an access token's default lifetime is assigned a random value ranging between 60-90 minutes (75 minutes on average). I suggest you save the `Refresh token` instead and then obtain the `access token` any time you want to query the users resource.

The reason for that is that the Refresh tokens have a longer lifetime than access tokens. The default lifetime for the tokens is 90 days and they replace themselves with a fresh token upon every use. As such, whenever a refresh token is used to acquire a new access token, a new refresh token is also issued. The Microsoft identity platform doesn't revoke old refresh tokens when used to fetch new access tokens. Securely delete the old refresh token after acquiring a new one. Refresh tokens need to be stored safely like access tokens or application credentials.

More about Refresh token in Microsoft identity platform can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens